# d7, large Taxonomy, entity reference, php error

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

when I like to add a content type "add/CCC" I get an PHP Error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 125MB". CCC includes an Entity Reference to Content Type AAA. AAA is large (10.000 Elements, including about 10 different taxonomies one of them with 2500 entries). When I change the reference in CCC to a test Contenttype BBB there is no error. Sometimes even to edit the structure of the content types of the entity reference leads to the PHP error.

Any ideas ?
Michael

Comment: When you having something that large then just simply up the PHP allowed memory and it should solve your problem.  What did you expect to happen with that much entries?

Comment: 125MB is the maximum. But I could not believe it to move to an expensive web hoster having in the content table 10K entries. Isn't it rather a problem how I use the entity reference module, is all the data loaded into the memory?